# Writing an effective method that reflects good OO design and fixes this broke method

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm working on my personal project and have recently had a bit of trouble with a method I wrote during the week.

This method compares user input from the same `JComboBox`. A before and after, if you will.  It then makes an appropriate adjustment to a 2nd `ComboBox` depending on the user's input into the first box. It took me a bit of effort to figure this out.  When I finally did, I was pretty happy with myself. Until I realized that the method uses a class variable and ruins any concept of good object-oriented design.

```
    /**
** missileBalancer compares the users input before and after selection and adjusts the contents of the OH missile count box as necessary.
** @param JComboBox combobox is the combobox concerning the OP counts, JComboBox combobox1 is the combobox concerning the OH counts, prevOH is the masterOH count.
** @return
** @throws
**/
public void missileBalancer(JComboBox combobox, JComboBox combobox1, int prevOP){
    int difference = 0;
    int newOH = 0;
    int newOP = (int) combobox.getSelectedItem(); //Current OP count
    int oldOH = (int) combobox1.getSelectedItem();//Current OH count --Adjusting this by the appropriate amount is the goal of this method
    int oldOP = prevOP;
    //oldOP is the OP that we are testing against it needs to be set by the program into a var that we can use in our test.
    if(newOP < oldOP){
        oldPac3 = newOP;//We need to keep track of our count outside of the method.
    }else if(newOP > oldOP){
    difference = newOP - oldOP; 
    newOH = oldOH - difference;
    combobox1.setSelectedItem(newOH);
    if(newOH < 0){//You cannot set selected item to a jcombobox with a negative number so in all cases where newOH is less than zero we simply set the selected item to 0.
        combobox1.setSelectedItem(0);
    }
    oldPac3 = newOP;    
    }

}//End Missile Balancer
```

The problem is with the user of the `oldPac3` variable. The method cannot always use this variable. I have variables for `oldGemT` and `oldGemC`, that this method needs to modify as appropriate. I can think of a couple ways to make this work, but I don't think any of them are very clean. I want the code for this method to be concise and elegant. Any help or some guidance in the right direction would be great.
This is the rewritten method. It does what needs doing, but I think it is ugly. I'm posting it because I don't want to give the impression that I'm looking for other people to solve my problems for me. I really just want to write better code.

```
/**
** missileBalancer compares the users input before and after selection and adjusts the contents of the OH missile count box as necessary.
** @param JComboBox combobox is the combobox concerning the OP counts, JComboBox combobox1 is the combobox concerning the OH counts, prevOH is the masterOH count.
** @return
** @throws
**/
public void missileBalancer(JComboBox combobox, JComboBox combobox1, int prevOP){
    int difference = 0;
    int newOH = 0;
    int newOP = (int) combobox.getSelectedItem(); //Current OP count
    int oldOH = (int) combobox1.getSelectedItem();//Current OH count --Adjusting this by the appropriate amount is the goal of this method
    int oldOP = prevOP;
    //oldOP is the OP that we are testing against it needs to be set by the program into a var that we can use in our test.
    if(newOP < oldOP){
        if(combobox.equals(pac_3OpCount)){
        oldPac3 = newOP;//We need to keep track of our count outside of the method.
        }
        else if(combobox.equals(gemCOpCount)){
            oldGemC = newOP;
        }
        else if(combobox.equals(gemtOpCount)){
            oldGemT = newOP;
        }
    }else if(newOP > oldOP){
    difference = newOP - oldOP; 
    newOH = oldOH - difference;
    combobox1.setSelectedItem(newOH);
    if(newOH < 0){//You cannot set selected item to a jcombobox with a negative number so in all cases where newOH is less than zero we simply set the selected item to 0.
        combobox1.setSelectedItem(0);
    }
    if(combobox.equals(pac_3OpCount)){
        oldPac3 = newOP;//We need to keep track of our count outside of the method.
        }
        else if(combobox.equals(gemCOpCount)){
            oldGemC = newOP;
        }
        else if(combobox.equals(gemtOpCount)){
            oldGemT = newOP;
        }   
    }       
}//End Missile Balancer
```

Comment: So you problem is that this method sometimes has to keep it's count in `oldPac3`, but sometimes in other variables such as `oldGemT` or `oldGemC`? Is that it? If it's the case we will not be able to answer without knowing in which cases that might happen and perhaps it would also help to know what all these variables mean.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, each of the old variables represents the user selection before the new selection; hence old vs new. When a variables needs to be modified directly correlates to which arguments where passed into the method. I rewrote the method last night so it does what I need and works, but I think it is hideous. Also I apologize if you find my var names confusing. Within the context of the program they make perfect sense and let me know exactly where I'm at in the program when I'm reading the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

1. Name your variables more descriptively.
2. Never copy-and-paste logic; if you find yourself doing so, make a new method or analyze *why* you're repeating it.
3. Don't pass around components if you don't have to (like `JComboBox`es).  In  general, Swing components are global variables.
4. Follow appropriate code formatting.  (Proper tabs, indentation, spaces between brackets, etc.)
5. Don't create unnecessary variables (i.e., `int oldOP = prevOP`)
6. Perform validations and error handling while doing dangerous things like downcasting.

---

I rewrote your entire method as follows just by following some decent object-oriented design practices.

```
public void balance() {
    if(getOperational() > count) {
        int adjustment = getAdjustment() - (getOperational() - count);
        adjustmentComboBox.setSelectedItem(adjustment < 0 ? 0 : adjustment);
    }
    count = getAdjustment();
}
```

What I'm going to do is walk through your code step-by-step, explain why I made certain changes, and then present the finished code.  I'll also point out any assumptions I've made in constructing my version.  I had to make a number of them due to your inexplicable variable names, but it shouldn't affect the final outcome drastically even if I made a mistaken guess as to what the variables meant.  You should just have to rename them to something appropriate.

So here are a few assumptions of mine right off the bat:

1. `prevOP` means the previous count of a given missile;
2. anywhere you use the infix `Op` or `OP`, it means something like "operational"; and,
3. anywhere you use the infix `Oh` or `OH`, it means something like "adjustment".

So let's get started!

```
public void missileBalancer(JComboBox combobox, JComboBox combobox1, int prevOP){
```

I was skeptical of this method immediately because it's very, very rare to have to pass around GUI elements like this when using Swing.  Ideally the combo boxes should all be declared as global fields in the class (i.e., `private JComboBox myComboBox`) so that all of your code can reference them as necessary.  Also, this really breaks Java naming conventions.  In general, a method name should be some kind of verb, never a noun like this.  If I was skimming code and I saw something called `missileBalancer`, I would assume it was an object, like of the `MissileBalancer` class.  Anything that's a noun in your code should be an actual object of some kind.

```
int newOP = (int) combobox.getSelectedItem();
int oldOH = (int) combobox1.getSelectedItem();
```

I'm not sure how you got this to compile.  I received compiler errors saying "Unable to cast Object to int."  In any case, that's easily solved by changing the downcast to `Integer` like so:

```
int newOP = (Integer) combobox.getSelectedItem();
```

This works thanks to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), and it's a handy trick to remember as you move forward with Java.  Even though this bit of code now works, it's still really bad practice since it's a completely unchecked (and therefore unsafe) downcast.  In other words, you're just assuming that `getSelectedItem()` will return something that can be cast to an `Integer`.  We'll return to this later to add some sanity checking and error handling.

```
int newOH = 0;
int newOP = (int) combobox.getSelectedItem();
int oldOH = (int) combobox1.getSelectedItem();
int oldOP = prevOP;

if(newOP < oldOP){
    if(combobox.equals(pac_3OpCount)) {
```

I just picked this bit out because it contains a lot of your variable declarations.  Your code was very, very difficult to decipher because of the names you chose for your variables.  If you intend to ever work on a large scale project, you will likely be working with other people.  And if you're working with other people, code readability is much, *much* more important than anything else.  There's a common adage that goes something like "A programmer's job is 10% development, 90% maintenance," and that's incredibly true.  You'll find that even if you're the only one working on a project, you'll come back to your code and look at this and ask yourself "...What in the *world* was I thinking here?"  Believe me, it happens more often than you think.

Bottom line: pick good variable names to try to make your code self-documenting.  Note that in the final version that I post below, you can pretty much know exactly what every line of code is trying to do just because I've chosen my variable and method names intuitively.

Also, if you want to be really Java-esque, follow the naming conventions.  No underscores in variable names (unless they're `public static final String CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS`).

```
if(combobox.equals(pac_3OpCount)){
    oldPac3 = newOP;//We need to keep track of our count outside of the method.
}
else if(combobox.equals(gemCOpCount)){
    oldGemC = newOP;
}
else if(combobox.equals(gemtOpCount)){
    oldGemT = newOP;
}
```

Do you see that this bit of code appears twice in your method?  It looks like you copied and pasted it.  A good rule of thumb is that if you ever hit CTRL+C and CTRL+V in succession, you are probably doing something the hard way.  If logic is repeated explicitly like this, it's a sign of bad design.  Either it should be refactored or the repeated logic should be encapsulated in its own, separate method.  I'll explain what I did with this later.

```
combobox1.setSelectedItem(newOH);
if(newOH < 0){//You cannot set selected item to a jcombobox with a negative number so in all cases where newOH is less than zero we simply set the selected item to 0.
    combobox1.setSelectedItem(0);
}
```

Here you are attempting to do some error handling, which is good.  In your comment you say "You cannot set selected item [in] a [JComboBox] with a negative number".  And that's very true.  But notice that you already do so *before* you perform your error check.  First you call `combobox1.setSelectedItem(newOH)` and *then* you check to see if `newOH` is less than zero.  But at that point, your code has already broken.  Always check for valid data before doing anything else with it.

Now I'll show you step-by-step how I refactored your code and present you with the final version at the end.

```
private JComboBox PAC3OperationalBox = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox GEMCOperationalBox = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox GEMTOperationalBox = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox PAC3AdjustmentBox = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox GEMCAdjustmentBox = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox GEMTAdjustmentBox = new JComboBox();
```

Notice right away how my variable names tell you *exactly* what they represent.  It's very easy to know what I intend each one to hold.  If I had just named them `comboBox1`, `comboBox2`, etc., or something even more arcane like `pacOPold`, it would be much harder to understand.  Java is by nature a verbose language which encourages explicit names for things.

```
public enum Missile {

    PAC_3, GEM_C, GEM_T;

    private int count = 0;
    private JComboBox operationalComboBox = null;
    private JComboBox adjustmentComboBox = null;
```

If you don't know [what an enum is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), now's a great time to learn.  It's a very useful data structure which lets you define exactly what its potential values are.  Here, it seems like your missile types are PAC-3s, GEM-Cs, and GEM-Ts, so that's what we have above.

This is why object-oriented programming is so powerful.  A missile is a thing in the world with its own properties, and so it is here.  This enum may have been more appropriately named `MissileType`, depending on your preference, since technically it will hold values for multiple missiles, like the `count`.  But having this data structure set up is what will let us completely rewrite your method in just five lines.

```
    public void setComboBoxes(JComboBox operationalBox, JComboBox adjustmentBox) {
        operationalComboBox = operationalBox;
        adjustmentComboBox = adjustmentBox;
    }
```

This will let us set the `JComboBox` references for each missile type upon initialization.  With these references, each missile will be able to calculate its values on its own.

```
    public int getOperational() {
        return MissileUtils.getComboBoxValue(operationalComboBox);
    }
```

I created another class called `MissileUtils` which performs simple utility functions.  I said that I wanted to do some sanity checking on your `(Integer) combobox.getSelectedItem()` statements, and here's the method where I do that (in MissileUtils`, not in the enum):

```
public static int getComboBoxValue(JComboBox comboBox) {
    Object selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    if(Integer.class.isInstance(selectedItem)) {
        return Integer.class.cast(selectedItem);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The combo box must have a valid integer selected.");
}
```

It's okay if you don't know what all this does.  Basically it's just checking to make sure that the `Object` returned by `getSelectedItem()` is actually an `Integer` before trying to downcast it.  If it's not, if will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I might've rewritten this method like the following, but in my production environment I really dislike using `instanceof` and this kind of downcasting.  (In general, it creates "code smell".)

```
if(selectedItem instanceof Integer) {
    return (Integer) selectedItem;
}
```

... Now back in the `Missile` enum, we put all the pieces together to see your refactored method:

```
public void balance() {
    if(getOperational() > count) {
        int adjustment = getAdjustment() - (getOperational() - count);
        adjustmentComboBox.setSelectedItem(adjustment < 0 ? 0 : adjustment);
    }
    count = getAdjustment();
}
```

It performs your check to see if the selected value from the first combo box is greater than the current count.  If so, it adjusts the second combo box's selected item, incorporating your error handling (checking if the new value is less than 0) using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java).  Then we set the count to the second combo box's value, since we do so in all cases.  (That was where you were copying and pasting that big block of code around.)

```
public MissileBalancer() {
    Missile.PAC_3.setComboBoxes(PAC3OperationalBox, PAC3AdjustmentBox);
    Missile.GEM_C.setComboBoxes(GEMCOperationalBox, GEMCAdjustmentBox);
    Missile.GEM_T.setComboBoxes(GEMTOperationalBox, GEMTAdjustmentBox);
}
```

Here's simply where we give the `Missile` types references to the needed `JComboBox`es.

```
private void callTheNewBalanceMethod(Missile missileType) {
    missileType.balance();
}
```

... And here's how you would call the new method.

---

## AND IN THE END, THERE WAS CODE

```
public class MissileBalancer {

    private JComboBox PAC3OperationalBox = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox GEMCOperationalBox = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox GEMTOperationalBox = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox PAC3AdjustmentBox = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox GEMCAdjustmentBox = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox GEMTAdjustmentBox = new JComboBox();

    private static enum Missile {

        PAC_3, GEM_C, GEM_T;

        private int count = 0;
        private JComboBox operationalComboBox = null;
        private JComboBox adjustmentComboBox = null;

        public int getOperational() {
            return MissileUtils.getComboBoxValue(operationalComboBox);
        }

        public int getAdjustment() {
            return MissileUtils.getComboBoxValue(adjustmentComboBox);
        }

        public void setComboBoxes(JComboBox operationalBox, JComboBox adjustmentBox) {
            operationalComboBox = operationalBox;
            adjustmentComboBox = adjustmentBox;
        }

        public void balance() {
            if(getOperational() > count) {
                int adjustment = getAdjustment() - (getOperational() - count);
                adjustmentComboBox.setSelectedItem(adjustment < 0 ? 0 : adjustment);
            }
            count = getAdjustment();
        }
    }

    public MissileBalancer() {
        Missile.PAC_3.setComboBoxes(PAC3OperationalBox, PAC3AdjustmentBox);
        Missile.GEM_C.setComboBoxes(GEMCOperationalBox, GEMCAdjustmentBox);
        Missile.GEM_T.setComboBoxes(GEMTOperationalBox, GEMTAdjustmentBox);
    }

    public static int getComboBoxValue(JComboBox comboBox) {
        Object selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if(Integer.class.isInstance(selectedItem)) {
            return Integer.class.cast(selectedItem);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The combo box must have a valid integer selected.");
    }

    private void callTheNewBalanceMethod(Missile missileType) {
        missileType.balance();
    }
```

---

*Note: setting the combo boxes into the* `enum` *this way will cause issues if you intend to use the class with concurrency, but the solution for that is left as an exercise for the reader.* :)

Comment: I want to sincerely thank you for taking the time to break this down and rebuild it. This is my first project and I'm doing it to help build my skill set. Your break down was really well put together. I'm probably 35% through my post-bacc in CS and it probably shows. When I wrote this code I knew it was garbage, but conceptually it was the best I could do at the moment. I don't know anyone in my life that could of done what you did so thats why I turned to the community. I'm not going to lie and say the rest of the code in my project is pristine, but nothing else is really this bad, thank you.

Comment: I still am very appreciative for the breakdown, but I don't think the code you wrote does what mine does. I think the reason why is because of my poor naming conventions which lead you to believe that OH stood for adjustment when it stands for "On Hand." Which is completely cool, cuz I still learned a lot from what you wrote and can see a lot of ways where I can make my code way more elegant. I certainly wasn't looking for anyone to do my work for me. So again sir, I thank you.

Comment: @BobBarker No problem.  Don't apologize for your work, either.  Everyone starts somewhere, and it's not that bad. :)  I think that regardless of the names the code does at least something close to what you were trying to accomplish, but without your entire class and the surrounding context it's hard to tell.  Good luck!